# Add different classes in div elements of list in query results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

How can I apply different `div` styles to the results of a query?

In the list of the results I want to set the style of `div`s based on their contents.

**Example:** In this list of results I want all results with bird's names to have different `div` styles from the animals.

```
1. Cow
2. Hen
3. Chick
4. Goat
5. Lion
6. Duck
```

**CSS:**

```
.birds{
  background:yellow;
}

.animals{
  background:red;
}
```

being very specific:

example in chat messages.. you can find different styles of messages between sender and receiver. for what I know they fetched all messages according to the criteria.
I just tried it

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        echo  '<div id="listOfMessages" class="">'.$row["sender"].":".$row["entry"]."<hr>". $row["date"].'</div>'."<hr>"."<br>";
        echo "<script> applyStyle();</script>";

         }

} else {
    echo "You don't have any converstaion with this user... send the message to start conversation with him/her";
}
```

The above code gave me the list of all messages and I added that JS to style the div as the below js function:

function applyStyle(){

```
if($("#listOfMessages:contains('badshah')")){
$("#listOfMessages").addClass("sender");
}else{
$("#listOfMessages").addClass("receiver");
}
}
```

It works but only for the first result(message) but all the following messages are not styled with this function.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need jquery/javascript for that. Just wrap your results in a span or if they are in li  and give them the attribute of class="birds" , class="animals"

Answer (score 0):

```js
var animals = ["Cow", "Hen", "Chick", "Goat", "Lion", "Duck"];
var creatureMap = {
  "birds": ["Hen", "Chick", "Duck"],
  "animals": ["Cow", "Goat", "Lion"]
};

var classifications = {
  "Hen": "birds",
  "Chick": "birds",
  "Duck": "birds",
  "Cow": "animals",
  "Goat": "animals",
  "Lion": "animals"
};

function render(entries, keep) {
  var render = document.getElementById('render');

  if (keep) {
    render.innerHTML = '';
  }

  entries.forEach(function(entry) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = entry;
    div.className = classifications[entry] || "animals";
    render.appendChild(div);
  });
};

render(animals);
```

```css
.birds {
  background: yellow;
}

.animals {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id = "render"></div>
```

Or

```css
    .birds{
        background:yellow;
       }

     .animals{
      background:red;
    }
```

```html
<div class="animals">
    <div>Cow</div>
    <div class="birds">Hen</div>
    <div class="birds">Chick</div>
    <div>Goat</div>
    <div>Lion</div>
    <div class="birds">Duck</div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.. but what i wanted is how to style the list from the database and not like that...

Comment: You mean not to use css at all, and apply the styling from html? What is the json or data structure that you are expecting from the database or server?

Comment: I want to use CSS, but what I find difficult is that when I query data from the database i get the list of all requested data from the database. but now what i want is to display those data inside <div></div> but with different classes according to the div contents.

Comment: So, my understanding that you query from the database, and you get a list of, for instance, of animals. They are just plain text, and you want to display them as HTML with the required style. Is that right?

Comment: Exactly @orabis... that's what I need and the styles must not be the same as I explained in my question...

Comment: How to you classify an animal or bird? Do you also get this from the database, or you hardcode it?

Comment: There is a column in database that stores data as  animal or bird Example duck----Bird. Lion ---- Animal. like this.

Comment: I updated the first snippet to render divs based on a list of animals. Deciding whether a create is animals or bird should be a part of your structure. Let e know if you need any change to the function to match your structure.

Comment: I think you may check my question again I added more specific information please.. I appreciate your help..

Answer (score 0):

Woow!!!... I got solution

because I have three columns in my database table, example below:
 |**Type**  |     **Group**    |**record_date**| 
|Cat    |   animal      | 22-12-2017|
|hen    |  bird          | 12-09-2017|

I tried doing this...

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        if($row["group"]=="animal"){

        echo  '<div id="list" class="animals">'.$row["type"]."<hr>". $row["record_date"].'</div>'."<hr>"."<br>";
        }else{

        echo  '<div id="list" class="birds">'.$row["type"]."<hr>". $row["record_date"].'</div>'."<hr>"."<br>";
        }


         }

} else {
    echo "You don't have any animal/bird recorded";
}
```

It worked!!!